# How to populate field from the view django? UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Tags: django, forms, view

I am trying to populate a field on a template form in Django. I have tried to do it on the view as well as a value on the form template but no luck. Here is my work

The outcome would be to populate username and email field from the resource model, but I am getting an **UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username** error.

Thanks

forms.py

```
class AdminRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    is_superuser = forms.BooleanField(),
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password Confirmation",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['password1',  'password2']

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if not password1 or not password2:
            raise ValidationError("Please confirm your password")

        if password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords must match")

        return password2
```

view.py

```
def admin_registration(request, username):
    resources = Resource.objects.get(username=username)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(reverse('index'))

    if request.method == "POST":
        resources = Resource.objects.get(username=username)
        admin_registration_form = AdminRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if admin_registration_form.is_valid():
            obj = admin_registration_form.save(commit=False)
            obj.is_superuser = True
            obj.save()

            user = auth.authenticate(username=[resources.username],
                                     password=request.POST['password1'])
            if user:
                auth.login(user=user, request=request)
                messages.success(request, "You have successfully registered")
                return redirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Unable to register your account at this time")
    else:
        admin_registration_form = AdminRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/registration.html', {
        "registration_form": admin_registration_form, 'email': resources.email })
```

models.py

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    ROLE = [
        ('Analyst', "Analyst"),
        ('Team Manager', "Team Manager"),
        ('Quality Auditor', "Quality Auditor"),
        ('Senior Analyst', "Senior Analyst"),
        ('', "")
    ]
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='')
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False, default='')
    email_sent = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROLE, default='')
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "eid"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: Where is your `User` model? Do you use generic? Why do you have `USERNAME_FIELD = "eid"` in `Resource`?

Comment: Hi , I don't have a User model as I am not adding more fields than the User model (from django.contrib.auth.models import User) is offering.   Eid field should be unique identifier .. I know the error usually means there ate duplicate value somewhere , but that's not the case

Answer (score 0):

In comment you said that you use generic `User` that Django is providing. Then your mistake is that you didn't specify `username` field in your Form. This field is needed if you haven't specified other `USERNAME_FIELD` but in `User` model. And you haven't, because you just import it. In that case every `User` created with `AdminRegistrationForm` has no `username`, or actually has - `None`. So as long as first `User` might be created, second would have same (`None`) `username` and it wouldn't be unique.

To fix that issue just add `username` field. Example:

```
class AdminRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField('username', max_length=150)
    ...
```

PS. `USERNAME_FIELD = "eid"` does nothing, because `Resource` is not an `User` model. Just create your own `CustomUser` model which is highly [recommended by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) itself :)